# Im Getting An Error While Uploading a Plugin "There has been a critical error on this website. Please check your site admin email for instructions."

Tags: wordpress, plugins

Whenever I Try To Upload A Plugin To Wordpress, This Error Shows Up "There has been a critical error on this website. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions."My website Isnt Down, But i cant upload any plugins due to this error
[Here is The Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05L3L.png)

I Have Tried Deactivating All Plugins And Switching Back To The Default Theme But It Did not Work.

Please Help

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall your wordpress or update. maybe error shows because of missing files and etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the plugin manually. It should solve the problem

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).